# A4Tech Web cam can not be detected because of conflict with any original mouse driver

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers, webcam

I have the web cam A4Tech PK-5MJ plug it on my USB but it was not detected and in device manager I see it under "other devices" with yellow rectangle over its name

The camera is driver free and I can not find any useful driver for it on the net other than "IM Magician" but no changes even after installing this software

I am on windows 7 sp1 64bit and I tried the web cam on same OS on another PC and it work fine !!

because of a note in the official site my webcam has a conflict with my original mouse (Cyborg RAT 7) driver and I make sure of that with install new Win 7 without installing my original mouse driver and it work but the big problem I still want to install my gaming mouse driver and use the webcam

so please advise how to make it work with my mouse driver

Comment: So you are saying that on your computer, if you remove the mouse driver, the Web Cam works as expected?

Comment: thanks for replay - yes. a4tech say on their website "ANY ORIGINAL MOUSE" so any one have a gaming mouse like me will have the same problem !! and I can not replace the mouse nor the webcam. - btw I sent a messages to a4tech support for never replied